# Is there something like Freelancer or Fiverr for random math questions?

Tags: online-resources

(This question isn't about `math.stackexchange` exactly, so I'm unsure if it belongs in `meta.math.stackexchange` instead or somewhere else entirely.)

I somewhat-regularly have small math problems that I want solutions for, and where I'd be willing to pay for a solution (plus an explanation of that solution), but I probably can't afford, justify, or *find* a "real"/"professional" consultant like [John D. Cook](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/services-2/).

Since I like sharing knowledge, ideally I'd put up a dollar bounty here on `math.stackexchange` but I don't expect that to be possible/allowed any time soon. Are there any good options here?

Comment: Is there a reason math.stackexchange _without_ the dollar bounty isn't sufficient for this purpose?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut most of the time I don't have a clear question to ask and instead I'm in a situation like "here is a vague issue plus an attempt at a solution, please help".

Those sorts of "questions" are, if I understand correctly, not favored here. Additionally they probably require more work to answer than a clear question, which means waiting for someone to donate their time is less effective.

Comment: The topic of payment for answers to questions has been discussed multiple times on Math Meta SE. See this answer https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32557/820543 which has links to other past discussions. Your best bet is to ask well written questions and hope the community answers them. It is probably not the answer you are looking for, but that is what it is here on MSE. Even if you do not get a full answer, you may get comments that point you in the right direction as long as you follow the question guidelines.

Comment: @eapi I don’t know where you are or what your circumstances are, but have you considered contacting a math department at a university/college near you? Often times graduate students do tutoring, and may be willing to fill the “consultant”role you’re describing at a more reasonable price. Based on the questions you’re asking here on MSE, you’d probably be more fun to discuss math with than yet another undergrad calculus student :)

Comment: @Joe ...huh, that's a good idea, and I do live in a city near a couple of universities. I guess that reduces the problem to finding out which grad student to contact, which sounds pretty approachable. Thanks!